# How to select a Radio Button using Mechanize in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize, web-crawler

i am building a crawler and i am using Mechanize. I wish to click on a radio button. How do i do that ?

Like for example there are two radio buttons say 'A' and 'B'. 
The website automatically selects B, but i want 'A' using Mechanize in ruby. I am also using the latest version on Mechanize.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. Probably the best would be to use the radio button's `name` or `id`:

```
form.radiobutton_with(:name => /b/).check
```

You could also do something like this:

```
form.radiobuttons.first.check
```

Which is more succinct, but more likely to break (if for instance you were to change the design of your form).

Comment: thanks a lot for that. I used `form.radiobuttons[0].checked=true` but that didnt make `form.radiobuttons[1].checked=false` i had to do that manually, anything you can suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a specific radio button out of a group of radio buttons, you can do so like this:

```
form.radiobutton_with(name: 'Choose wisely', value: 'Carpenter Goblet').check
```

This will allow you to choose the specific radio button with the desired value, this is better than selecting the radio button from its group using an index.